# Inserting a picture - xlwings

Tags: excel, image, pywin32, xlwings

I'm curious if there is a possibility to insert an image (for example produced by Matplotlib) into an Excel sheet using xlwings. I've seen some tips regarding handling charts, but not images. If not, then I guess it's worth trying pywin32?

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: I've found the solution. It's as easy as importing pywin32 and using the code:

Shapes.AddPicture(FileName, LinkToFile=False, SaveWithDocument=True, Left, Top, Width, Height)

where FileName is path to the image...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xlwings 0.19.5

```
sht.pictures.add(fig,name='Chart',left='A1',top='A1')
```

Should work to add a picture to Excel. Change fig to your image.